# MiniMRCluster permissions issue on travis ci

Tags: hadoop, travis-ci

I'm trying to run a job against a mini cluster that I start on travis CI. I'm currently getting the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Error Reading IndexFile
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.IndexCache.readIndexFileToCache(IndexCache.java:113)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.IndexCache.getIndexInformation(IndexCache.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$MapOutputServlet.doGet(TaskTracker.java:4039)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer$QuotingInputFilter.doFilter(HttpServer.java:850)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)2
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Owner 'travis' for path /tmp/hadoop-travis.16542/mapred/local/3_0/taskTracker/travis/jobcache/job_20140509234904614_0004/attempt_20140509234904614_0004_m_000001_0/output/file.out.index did not match expected owner 'travis.16542'
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SecureIOUtils.checkStat(SecureIOUtils.java:177)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SecureIOUtils.openForRead(SecureIOUtils.java:110)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SpillRecord.<init>(SpillRecord.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SpillRecord.<init>(SpillRecord.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.IndexCache.readIndexFileToCache(IndexCache.java:109)
    ... 23 more
14/05/09 23:51:08 WARN mortbay.log: /mapOutput: java.io.IOException: Error Reading IndexFile
```

I've tried using a different version of jetty or a different version of java per things I've found online, but that didn't work (though maybe I didn't set those in the proper way).

Comment: Can you please link to your Travis build? Thanks!

Comment: Here: https://travis-ci.org/twitter/scalding/jobs/28063576